# Android get rotated bitmap. (Image straightening)

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview, transform, instagram

I am trying to rotate a bitmap and crop out a valid Rectangle out of it, and then save it on the disk. What i am trying to do is explained in the following link:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IIhBw.png

Black is the original image. Red is rotated image (by 15 degrees here) and green is the valid portion of the red image.

This feature is similar to the Image straightening which Instagram app does.

So far, I have tried this:

```
public static Bitmap getRotatedBitmap2(Bitmap bmp, int rotation){
    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    matrix.preRotate(rotation);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp, 0, 0,
            bmp.getWidth(), bmp.getHeight(),
            matrix, false);
    return bitmap;
}
```

This rotates the bitmap but it shrinks in size, also the rotated bitmap is enclosed is an black rectangle. i need to get rid of the out-bounding black rectangle. Also, How can I obtain the valid portion of bitmap?

Comment: Check my answer for this issue.
http://stackoverflow.com/a/38868813/3640366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Aviary](https://www.aviary.com) and [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) are libraries that can help to achieve the results asked in the question, as well perform other Bitmap operations and Image Manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

I know you already solved this question, but if somebody is looking for another solution, you can check this library [image-rotator](https://github.com/palicka/image-rotator) that solves problem like this or very similar.