# How can i remove black background of after rotate Bitmap image in android 5.0

Tags: android, android-imageview

i have try to remove the black background after the rotate image in my code

```
Bitmap rotate(float x, Bitmap bitmapOrg) {

    int width = bitmapOrg.getWidth();
    int height = bitmapOrg.getHeight();
    int newWidth = 200;
    int newHeight = 200;

    float scaleWidth = ((float) newWidth) / width;
    float scaleHeight = ((float) newHeight) / height;

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    matrix.postScale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);
    matrix.postRotate(x);

    Bitmap resizedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmapOrg, 0, 0, width,height, matrix, true);
    //Canvas canvas = new Canvas(resizedBitmap);
    //canvas.drawColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);


    return resizedBitmap;
}
```

how can i remove black background i have seen that only in my android lolipop , i also try in my emulator Google galaxy nexus - 4.2.2  in that black background is not display .

[image]

Comment: Check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38868813/3640366

Comment: still not working it will getting black background behind image .thanks for the response.

Comment: Could you post your code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use `resizedBitmap.setHasAlpha(true);`
put that line of code right after you declare your bitmap.